# Onpostexecute wont update the textview

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, textview

i'm doing create an catalogue movie app,i have problem on detailactivity,my problem is,when i click the first movie,its success show the movie detail,then i press back button,and i click another movie,but it still showing the firstmovie detail i click,i see the log,the title and any,is updated,but the textview in the activity is not updated,how can i fix this?

DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txt_title,txt_desc,txt_release;
ImageView img_posterd;

private Context context;


public static List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>();

public static String API_KEY = "f00e74c69ff0512cf9e5bf12856******";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);



    Intent i = getIntent();
    String idmov = i.getStringExtra("idmovie");

    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+idmov+"?api_key="+API_KEY+"&language=en-US";
    txt_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title_detail);
    txt_desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_desc_detail);
    txt_release = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_release);
    img_posterd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_poster_detail);
    new GetMovieTask(txt_title,txt_desc,txt_release,img_posterd).execute(url);


}

private class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, List<String>, List<String>>{

    TextView txt_title,txt_desc,txt_release;
    ImageView img_poster;

    public GetMovieTask(TextView txt_title, TextView txt_desc, TextView txt_release,ImageView img_poster) {

        this.txt_title = txt_title;
        this.txt_desc = txt_desc;
        this.txt_release = txt_release;
        this.img_poster = img_poster;

    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String title;
        String desc;
        String release;
        String posterUrl;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputString;
            while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(inputString);
            }


            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            title = String.valueOf(object.getString("title"));
            desc = String.valueOf(object.getString("overview"));
            release = String.valueOf(object.getString("release_date"));
            posterUrl = String.valueOf(object.getString("backdrop_path"));
            String finalPos = posterUrl = POSTER_BASE_URL + "original" + posterUrl;

            LIST.add(title);
            LIST.add(desc);
            LIST.add(release);
            LIST.add(finalPos);

            Log.d("titlenya", title);
            Log.d("desc", desc);
            Log.d("release", release);
            Log.d("posterUrl", finalPos);

            urlConnection.disconnect();


        }catch (IOException | JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return LIST;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String title = result.get(0);
        String desc = result.get(1);
        String release = result.get(2);
        String poster = result.get(3);
        txt_title.setText("Title : " +title);
        txt_desc.setText("Description : " +desc);
        txt_release.setText("Release Date : " +release);
        Picasso.with(context).load(poster).into(img_posterd);

    }

}
```

[image: This is my log,the title is update,but on the textview is not change]

[image: my id is changed too]

Comment: Please log the idmov that you are getting in the extras, check if it is the correct value.

Comment: check my question again,i already add the picture

Comment: are you getting any exception? Just in case you have added any filters to your logcat, remove them and observe again

Comment: no i didnt get any exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please find the updated version of the DetailActivity.java

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txt_title, txt_desc, txt_release;
ImageView img_posterd;

public static String API_KEY = "******";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String idmov = i.getStringExtra("idmovie");
    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + idmov + "?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&language=en-US";
    txt_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title_detail);
    txt_desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_desc_detail);
    txt_release = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_release);
    img_posterd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_poster_detail);
    new GetMovieTask().execute(url);
}

private class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, List<String>, List<String>> {

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        List<String> detailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String title;
        String desc;
        String release;
        String posterUrl;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String inputString;

            while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(inputString);
            }

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            title = String.valueOf(object.getString("title"));
            desc = String.valueOf(object.getString("overview"));
            release = String.valueOf(object.getString("release_date"));
            posterUrl = String.valueOf(object.getString("backdrop_path"));
            String finalPos = posterUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/" + "original" + posterUrl;

            detailsList.add(title);
            detailsList.add(desc);
            detailsList.add(release);
            detailsList.add(finalPos);

            Log.d("titlenya", title);
            Log.d("desc", desc);
            Log.d("release", release);
            Log.d("posterUrl", finalPos);

            urlConnection.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return detailsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String title = result.get(0);
        String desc = result.get(1);
        String release = result.get(2);
        String poster = result.get(3);
        txt_title.setText("Title : " + title);
        txt_desc.setText("Description : " + desc);
        txt_release.setText("Release Date : " + release);
      Picasso.with(DetailActivity.this).load(poster).into(img_posterd);
    }
}
}
```

You were using a static LIST and that is the cause of the problem. You were getting the details like LIST.get(0),LIST.get(1)..... so as the list was static the previous data still existed and you were always getting the details of first movie you have opened.

Also you already have all the textviews and the imageview as global objects so no need to pass them to the AsyncTask's constructor

Comment: I have shared the solution above, have tested it and is working as expected. Please go through the solution. It is simple remove the static LIST and created a list in doInBackground of AsyncTask, also removed the constructor to which you were passing the views that was unnecessary.

Comment: NICE ONE SIR,its worked thx :),,but i not fully understand ,, when you say "You were using a static LIST and that is the cause of the problem" ,, can you explain more??

Comment: public static List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>(); this line was causing the problem you should not use a static list, it will stay in the memory. It is a class variable which means it only instantiates once per class instead of the instance. So Your detail activity will have same LIST for every instance created. Hope you understand now. Still if you have any queries related to this please go through https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java

Comment: okayy sir thx one question again ,, ca you explain more about "Also you already have all the textviews and the imageview as global objects so no need to pass them to the AsyncTask's constructor" ,, i just found out,that way will work :D

Comment: They are already accessible for your inner Asynctask class please read more at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm